# Folder for Commit changes in RMS j2me

Tags: mobile, java-me, rms

I mentioned folder name in emulator setting (to commit RMS changes) but my question is:

Such folder will be available on real phone or not while running on it?

Comment: No, that folder is only part of the emulator. Tells where on your computer you want RMS data to be saved. No such folder will appear on phone.

Comment: If I want to store data permanently then what should i do?? because it stores data permanently only when I mentioned folder name....otherwise it will erase the data as I close the application....I want to create permanent file in real device

Comment: The folder is only necessary with the emulator. Anything you save with RMS methods, is permanently stored on real devices. The folder you create with your emulator, is not transferred with the MIDlet though. You can't create a MIDlet with pre-saved records. You need to create such records manually e.g. on the first run.